# How can I execute one query after another and process that data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an app.get that will return customer data and customer purchases. Inside this app.get I need run two mysql calls and build a an array to pass back.

How can I execute one query after another and process that data?

```
app.get('/customer', function (req,res) {
    var response1 = [];
    var response2 = [];
    var processedData = [];

        connection.query('QUERY HERE', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (!err){
              response.push({rows});
        } else {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
    });

    //for loop 'response' results and perform another query
     for (var i = 0; i < response1.length; i++) {
         var row = response1[i];
         connection.query('QUERY HERE FOR row.customerid', function(err, rows, fields) {
           if (!err){
              processedData.push({'Customer Name:' : row.customername, 'purchases' : rows});
            } else {
              res.status(400).send(err);
            }
         });
       }


    //Send json back
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(processedData));

});
```

Comment: Add your loop and second query inside the if block. BTW, in JS we'd usually use if (err) { return res.status(400.send(err) }, then any code after that block executes when there's not an error and need not be inside a block. Not a rule, just a little cleaner. If you do it this way, your loop and second query would come after the if block.

Comment: Hi @Nocturno ,  added my second query above as well as the for loop. The syntax might not be 100% but just wanted to outline was I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yeah I saw what you were trying to accomplish, and I wanted to show you the standard async way before others tried to convince you to use complicated async libraries. What I wanted you to see is that you must add your loop and second query inside the first callback. That callback executes only after the async function returns. That is how asynchronous behavior works. I will rework your code and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very convenient module called [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) that provides a bunch of functions for doing complex async operations. Particularly,

- [async.waterfall()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall) is great when you need to pass down results from one async operation/task to another.
- [async.mapSeries()](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#mapSeries) is great when you need to create a new array with results from an array of async operation/tasks.

Let's use both.

If I understood your code correctly, the code would look something similar to

```
app.get('/customer', function (req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
        // each task is passed a callback 'cb' as last argument;
        // you MUST call it at least and at most once within each task;
        // if you pass an error into the callback as the first argument, it will stop the async function
        function task1 (cb1) {
            //connection.query('QUERY HERE', function(err, rows, fields) {
            //    if (err) return cb1(err);  // stop waterfall() if an error occurred
            //    cb1(null, rows, fields);   // pass results down to next task
            //});

            connection.query('QUERY HERE', cb1); // shorter version
        },
        function task2 (rows, fields, cb2) {

            // iterate and run async operation over each element in array 'rows'
            async.mapSeries(rows, function getPurchases (row, cb3) {
                connection.query('QUERY HERE FOR row.customerid', function (err, purchases, fields) {
                    if (err) return cb3(err);  // stop mapSeries() if an error occurred
                    cb3(null, { 'Customer Name': row.customername, 'purchases': purchases })
                });
            }, function (err, customers) {
                // when mapSeries() is done iterating OR if an error occurred, it will come here

                if (err) return cb2(err); // stop waterfall() if an error occurred 
                cb2(null, customers)
            });

        // }, cb2); // shorter version

        }
    ], function (err, customers) {
        // when waterfall() is done all its tasks OR if an error occurred, it will come here

        // handle error and send response here
    });
});
```